# Moments of waiting time in a G/G/1 queue

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Are there any results for moments of waiting or sojourn time(total time spent by a job in the system including its own service) for a G/G/1 queue. I know that in the special case of M/G/1 queues the moments can be derived from the  Laplace–Stieltjes transform given by [Pollaczek–Khinchine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollaczek%E2%80%93Khinchine_formula) formula. Are there any similar results for queues where both service and arrival follow some general distributions? Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: You can get first moment bounds for G/G/1, see (I think it is in the appendix of chapter 3 or around there): http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/datanets.html

Comment: Thanks! Any idea for second moment?